# Reading a File Name with PHP

Tags: php, filesystems

I'm writing a news script, and I'm having trouble making a way for the files to be deleted.

How can I change this script so that the `<input type="checkbox" />` has a `value` of the file in the same row?

```
<?php
    // This function reads all available news
    function getNewsList(){

       $fileList = array();

        // Open the actual directory
        if ($handle = opendir("news")) {
            // Read all file from the actual directory
            while ($file = readdir($handle))  {
                if (!is_dir($file)) {
                    $fileList[] = $file;
            }
            }
        }   

        rsort($fileList);

        return $fileList;
    }

    // new

    $list = getNewsList();
    print("<table>\n");
    print("<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>Article Title:</td><td>Post Date:</td></tr>\n");
    foreach ($list as $value) {
        $newsData = file("news/".$value);
        $newsTitle  = $newsData[0];
        $submitDate = $newsData[1]; 
        unset ($newsData['0']);
        unset ($newsData['1']);

        $newsContent = "";
        foreach ($newsData as $value) {
            $newsContent .= $value;
        }

            print("<tr>");
            print("<td><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"check_files[]\" value=\"$file\" /></td>");
            print("<td>$newsTitle</td>");
            print("<td>");
            print("$submitDate");
            print("</td>");
            print("</tr>\n");

    }  
    print("</table>\n");
```

I have a similar script for managing files, and it's something like `$dirArray[$index]` for the file name, but I can't figure out how to adapt this script to work the same way, because I'm too new to PHP.

Thanks for the help!

EDIT: This is the line where the file name needs to be: (instead of $file, which doesn't work for some reason):

`print("<td><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"check_files[]\" value=\"$file\" /></td>");`

Comment: We don't see the function defined at the top of your script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$file` variable isn't defined anywhere, you could try this:

replace

```
$newsData = file("news/".$value);
```

with

```
$file="news/".$value;
$newsData = file($file);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your script, it looks like the current file name is stored in `$value`, because `$list = getNewsList();` is an array of filenames, and your doing a foreach on it : `foreach ($list as $value) {`

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the second foreach loop with:

```
foreach ($newsData as $content) {
    $newsContent .= $content;
}
```

and then use this line to show the file:

`print("<td><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"check_files[]\" value=\"$value\" /></td>");`